# Prove that C is contained in D since all elements of D are a subset of C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ = any non-empty set, $C$ = { {$a$} | $a \in X$ }, $D$ = { $E \subseteq C$ | $E$ or $E^c$ is finite}

So, is it true that $C \subseteq D$?

I think the above statement is false since for instance,

Suppose if $K \in C$ such that $K$ or $K^c$ are both infinite, then $K \notin D$, which implies $C \not\subseteq D$

Please clarify, thanks.

Comment: In which way is this a question about [tag:measure-theory]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was watching this video about measure theory which explains this while describing the properties of algebra. (https://youtu.be/h5TaNHX0Txc?t=1142). The only difference is that D here is represented as an algebra generated by C in the video.

Comment: That doesn't make a your question a Measure Theory question. And another thing. Suppose that, say, $X=\{1,2,3\}$. Then $C=\bigl\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\bigr\}$. Then, how can $K$ be both an element of $X$ and an element of $C$? After all, $K\cap C=\emptyset$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You're right! K can't be an element of both X and C. I've edited the question based upon that. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K\in C$, then $K=\{a\}$, for some $a\in X$, and therefore $K$ itself is finite (it has one and only one element).

Comment: Can understand the part that $K$ is finite because it has only one element $a$.
Just curious to know how come it's possible to have an infinite set $a$ inside a finite set $K$?

Comment: The set $a$ is *not* $K$. What's inside $K$ is $\{a\}$, which has a single element. For instance, $\Bbb N$ is an infinite set, but $\{\Bbb N\}$ has a single element.

Comment: Got you. Thank you for explaining this clearly though my questions may look elementary. :)